# Return type for function returning an async closure?

Tags: rust

Coming from Scala, I am used to partially applied functions.
I have the following async function for which I want to prefill one argument by building a closure:

```rust
pub async fn my_func(
    arg1: SomeType, 
    arg2: SomeOtherType, 
    secret: String
) -> Result<SomeResultType, Error> {...}
 
let partially_applied_func = |arg1: SomeType, arg2: SomeOtherType| 
    {
        my_func(arg1, arg2, get_my_secret_code().clone())
    };
```

.. So that I can then pass around `partially_applied_func`.

This syntax works fine, but the `get_my_secret_code()` is code I want to further abstract away in my library. I want to basically expose a single public function that produces the `partially_applied_func` closure:

```rust
pub (async?) fn make_closure() -> ??? {
   |arg1: SomeType, arg2: SomeOtherType| 
        {
            my_func(arg1, arg2, get_my_secret_code().clone())
        }
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me the result type of `make_closure`. My IDE suggests something along the lines of `fn(_, _) -> Future<Output = Result<SomeResultType>, Error>` which is incorrect.

**The requirement is that the returned closure is `async`, and this seems to make it more difficult. Can someone offer advice on how to formulate the proper result type?**