# How do I refactor an async closure to its own method?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures

Let's suppose I have the following main:

```rust
async fn main_to_refactor() {
    let objects = [0, 1, 2];
    let dependency = Arc::new(Dependency::default());
    
    let res = futures::stream::iter(
        objects.map(|item| {
            // need to clone the dependency, because it may outlive the current scope
            let dependency = dependency.clone();
            
            async move {
                drop(dependency); // do something with the dependency...
                item == 2
            }
        })
    )
    .buffered(3)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .await;
    
    println!("{res:?}"); // [false, false, true]
}
```

Everything works, but I do several parallel tasks, so I want to refactor the task itself out:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let objects = [0, 1, 2];
    let dependency = Arc::new(Dependency::default());
    
    let res = futures::stream::iter(
        objects.map(do_task(&dependency))
    )
    .buffered(3)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .await;
    
    println!("{res:?}"); // [false, false, true]
}

fn do_task<R>(dependency: &Dependency) -> 
    impl Fn(u32) -> R 
        where R: Future<Output = bool> {
    let dependency = dependency.clone();
    
    |item: u32| async move {
        let _ = dependency; // do something with the dependency...
        return item == 2
    }
}
```

However, in this case the compiler complains:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:52:17
   |
47 |   fn do_task<R>(dependency: &Dependency) -> 
   |              - this type parameter
...
52 |       |item: u32| async move {
   |  _________________^
53 | |         let _ = dependency; // do something with the dependency...
54 | |         return item == 2
55 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected type parameter `R`, found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `R`
                 found opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = bool>`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

It seems to have an issue with the fact `R` is not compatible with the return type.

How do I refactor the `|item| { ... }` closure to its own function?

---

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8d2057e9b8ea6f7c22dc1ce4cb299cc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return an async function from a function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61167939/return-an-async-function-from-a-function-in-rust)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352455/return-type-for-function-returning-an-async-closure.

Comment: Why do you use `#![feature(async_closure)]`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman a prev version of the playground used an `async move |item|` rather than `|item| async move`, I tried to play around with the types before posting the question and the annotation got there by mistake, you can ignore it!

Comment: Regarding your prev comment, is it truly not possible to avoid boxing in this case?

Comment: This is a duplicate nevertheless, but I've got some idea. Let me play with it...

Comment: Returning the Future means I'd need to clone each dependency before-hand. In the full-fledged code I have multiple task, each with their own dependencies, so it would quickly get messy. Boxing and unboxing every-time is preferable to this but still not ideal, it shouldn't be needed as the type is not dynamic?

Comment: Yes, this works, although I should polish it a little. I will close this as duplicate and soon post there.

Comment: Posted an answer to your question (indirectly) there.

Comment: I get an error while trying to compile your type: the trait bound `F: Fn(Arg) -> ::Future` is not satisfied [E0277] the trait `Fn(Arg) -> ::Future` is not implemented for `F`

Comment: [It works for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5524196c109c7a00e461eadfb01e1451), so you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Yes you're right I thought `let _ = dependency` was enough to get the borrow checker to consume the dependency, but it isn't: here's what happens with a closure: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da3c455f8ab3538fe86aabd4283f894e

I guess this is where my question and the one that was marked as a duplicate differ, in the other question there's a higher order function, which is not closing over any variable, thus it's not a closure.

I'm not sure whether I should open another similar question or just edit. PS: Edited this one

Comment: If you move out of captured variables, you need a `FnOnce` closure. Change `Fn` to `FnOnce`. That's not related to async.